# Script to automatically send a Sheet by email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automate by a script the sending of a Sheet (active or not) of a workbook and only one sheet and not the whole workbook to a list of email addresses. Furthermore, I would like the Sheet to be converted to excel format when it is attached to the email.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: I strongly recommend you to take a look into [StackOverflow: How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In order to get a prompt response you can summarize the title and what's actually your expected code behavior. It's helpful for the community. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  const sheetToPrint = 'SPREADSHEET_NAME'; // name of the sheet to print
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME'); // the sheets to use
  const email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME').getRange('RANGE').getValue().toString(); // grab the email address from the specified cell 
  const subject = `SUBJECT - ${ss.getName()}`; // the subject of the email
  const body = "BODY"; // body of the email
  const shID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId()); // url of the spreadsheet
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=xlsx' + // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    '&gid='+shID; // the sheet's Id
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // generate the file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // send the email to the specified address with the specified body text and attached file
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: `EKOL Hungary - ${ss.getName()}` + ".xlsx",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/xlsx"
        }]
    });
}
```

Just substitute the `SPREADSHEET_NAME`, `SHEET_NAME`, `RANGE`, and `BODY` to what is true for your spreadsheet.

You can add a Trigger under the Triggers menu point (left side of the Script Editor) to automatically run the script whenever you want it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I failed to use it
But by combining several scripts, I found one that works:

```js
function onSubmit(e){
Logger.log('submit ran');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

//Send active sheet as email attachment

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var ssID = ss.getId();
var sheetgId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
var sheetName = ss.getName();

var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

var email = "xxx@xx";
var subject = "xxxxx";
var body = "xxxxx";

var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export?" + "format=xlsx" + "&gid="+sheetgId+ "&portrait=false" + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
headers: {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
}
});

var contents = result.getContent();

MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject ,body, {attachments:[{fileName:sheetName+".xlsx", content:contents, mimeType:"application//xlsx"}]});
};
```

Now what I would like is to be able to send the sheet to email addresses located on another sheet.
Also in "subject", I would like to combine "xxxx" + a date in a cell of the active sheet: "xxxx dd / mm / yyyy"

I haven't figured out how to do it yet !!!